# What is the difference between connectionURL and connectionType in maven-scm-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-scm

What is the difference, in maven-scm-plugin, between the `connectionUrl` property and the `connectionType` property?

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `maven-scm-plugin` [to check out source code](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html), your POM file can contain both a `connectionalURL` and a `developerConnectionURL`. The `connectionType` property tells `maven-scm-plugin` which one of those two connectionURL properties to use when checking out code from source management.